# tinkercad arduino simulator integers being outputted as larger numbers than they are?

Tags: simulator

I am using an Arduino simulator on [www.tinkercad.com](http://www.tinkercad.com) (a seemingly nice free product from Autodesk).  Working on conversion of an integer to a 16 bit binary string for output to a DAC, but unfortunately even at the first step I am getting unexpected behavior.

```
void setup()
{
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Sanity Check\n");
  uint16_t num = 12000;
  Serial.print("\nNumber: " + String(num) + "\n");
  delay(3000);
}
```

Surprisingly the above code gave the following output:

```
Sanity Check

Number: 12222
```

Is there something I am doing wrong, or something wrong with the simulator?   The error seems to crop up with any value over 10000.  10001, 10002, 10003 all print as 10000.  11000, 11001, 11002, 11003 all print as 11111.  etc, etc.  What could be going on?

Comment: My Uno prints “Number: 12000”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bug. No other explanation. Real hardware (Arduino Uno) prints 12000.

Even the debugger tells me that the value of that variable is 12000.

[image: debug]

Outputs:

```
Number: 12222 
12000 
12222 something
```

Most interestingly if you `Serial.println()` the number, it is outputted correctly. The bug must be in the constructor of the `String` object, as demonstrated by the "test" `String`. This bug also occurs on other data types, e.g. `int`.

If you only use direct `Serial.print[ln]` calls you should be able to workaround that bug.

Answer (score 1):

Tinkercad is (was) a very good simulator but it has stopped updates.
Here is the output from the free Arduino simulator from [here](https://wokwi.com)

This [project](https://wokwi.com/arduino/projects/295390167781343757) is used for the below screenshot

[image]

Here is an [article](https://www.hackster.io/write2puneeth/tinkercad-versus-wokwi-arduino-simulator-5ab08d) pointing some more features of the simulator